# RTL8191SE wireless card not working in Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, wifi

I'm having trouble getting my wireless card seen in debian squeeze. `iwconfig` only shows `eth0` and `l0` but no `wlan0`. `ifconfig wlan0 up` says theres no such device.
I compiled a backport kernel and I now have "2.6.39-bpo.2-686-pae". I downloaded the `rtl8191se` driver from the Realtek site. It said it needs kernel version 2.6.35 or above. So now that I have 2.6.39 all should be fine. However when I run `make` in the firmware driver it says

```
make entering directory lib/modules/2.6.39-bpo.2-686-pae/build
no rule to make target 'modules'
Stop.
```

Is there a problem with my `make`? I installed i386 packages as theres no i686 packages on the Debian site. However, my kernel is i686 it seems. Is that a problem?

Comment: More steps, please. Where did you unpack the source files? What instructions did you follow, if any? In what directory did you type make?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is in 3.0 onwards. See [Linux Kernel Driver DataBase](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/RTL8192SE.html).

So what you need to do is

1. install a 3.0 kernel or later. Debian has sources and binaries for
   3.1 and 3.2, 3.1 in testing and unstable and 3.2 in experimental. See [linux source package page](http://packages.qa.debian.org/l/linux-2.6.html). The linux-2.6 source package name is confusing, but it looks like they haven't changed the name yet to 3.x.
2. Install the [firmware-realtek](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-realtek) package.

You could of course use an external kernel source, but you are better off using a Debian kernel. Note that this driver is probably already enabled in the binary kernel as a module, so in that case you don't need to do anything except install the firmware. If you are compiling from source, make sure to select this module to build.